# I'm seeing myself age well-rounded and full in form. Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm seeing myself age well-rounded and full in form.

Comment: It does if you're a wine or a cheese. Not so much for people, though.

Comment: It does, although it uses non-traditional grammar. I think it makes sense for people; a woman can be both physically well-rounded/full in form and psychologically well-rounded. Fun play on the expressions!

Comment: ahaha! In that case I would feel like I've conveyed what I wanted to since the pun was intended. It was a reaction to someone saying "your cheeks have become chubbier"

Comment: It sounds like you view yourself as fat.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense. It doesn't require punctuation if the intent is accomplished without it. Punctuation obviously alters the meaning or accent. I am seeing myself age, well rounded and full in form. I am seeing myself age well, rounded and full in form. I am seeing myself age, well, rounded and full in form. I am seeing myself, age well rounded and full, in form. I am seeing myself age, well rounded and full, in form. I am, seeing myself age, well rounded and full in form. I am seeing myself ? age well rounded and full in form.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not exactly correct. It is just a lack of punctuation.
Or you could try any alternative: something more along the lines of "I'm seeing myself age - becoming well rounded and full in form" or "well rounded and fuller in form"/"rounding well and becoming fuller in form".

Comment: Or if we just got rid of the last part of the sentence and just said "I guess I'm seeing myself age well-rounded."

Comment: Or, @NajeebaFathima, "As I age, I'm becoming more well-rounded." :-)